# Post data to PHP file from HTML form where value of input types are set using jQuery's .val() function

Tags: php, jquery, html

[Link to checkout the form](http://www.unizhost.com/a/phone/)
Here's what i tried in Jquery:

```
$('#third_n').bind('keypress click',function(){

    $('p#p_service').text($('#id_service').val());
    $('p#p_rate').text($('#id_rate').val());
    $('p#p_imei').text($('#imei').val());
    $('p#p_device').text($('#id_device').val());

    var a= $('#id_device').val();
    var b= $('#id_rate').val();
    var c= $('#id_service').val();
    alert(a);
    alert(b);
    alert(c);
    });
```

Her's the part of jquery code that set the .val() function

```
var ser_val = $('#ssamsung').val();
$('#id_service').val(ser_val);
$('#id_device').val('iPhone 5');
$('p#rate').text($('#id_rate').val());
```

And my corresponding HTML:

```
<form class="nobottommargin" method="post" action="shop_paypal.php">

<label>IMEI: <small>*</small></label>
<input type="text" value="" class="required input-block-level"  id="imei" maxlength="15" required/>
<label>Cost:</label>
<input id="id_rate" type="hidden" name="na_rate">
<p id="rate"></p>
<label>Notice:</label>
<p id="p_notice"></p>
<label>Details:</label>
<p id="p_details"></p>
<label>FIRST NAME:</label>
<input type="text" value="" id="FN" name="first_n" required/>
<label>LAST NAME:</label>
<input type="text" value="" id="LN" name="first_n" required/>
<label>EMAIL: </label>
<input type="email" value="" id="EML" name="first_EML" required/>
<label>Device:</label>
<input id="id_device" type="hidden" name="na_device" value="">
<p id="p_device"></p>
<label>IMEI:</label>
<p id="p_imei"></p>
<label>Service:</label>
<input id="id_service" type="hidden" name="na_service" value="">
<p id="p_service"></p>
<label>Rate:</label>
<p id="p_rate"></p>
<label>Name:</label>
<p id="p_name"></p>
<label id="l_email">Email:</label>
<p id="p_email"></p>
<input type="submit" class="simple-button large" id="submit">
</form>
```

Till here every thing is fine, getting right alerts via jquery and the text correctly gets set in`<p>` tags.

But this Corresponding PHP Code echoes nothing:

```
<?php
session_start();
   $rate = $_POST['na_rate'];
   $device = $_POST['na_device'];
   $service= $_POST['na_service'];
   $email = $_POST['first_EML'];
   echo $email;
   echo $device;
   echo $service;
   die(0);
```

I'm not sure why? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How does your `<form>` look like? Sounds to me as if your method might be GET or that you didn't even put it in a `<form>` element, or with the wrong `action` attr

Comment: your hidden fields have no `value` attribute, and you're not setting any via your JS code, so your form is basically submitting permanently empty fields.

Comment: @MarcB they simply have no default value, but if he submits with user input it should work

Comment: @ChenAsraf: **WHAT** user input? they're hidden fields.

Comment: @PranavCBalan: Yes i know that, i'm glad you pointed out the issue. But the thing is i don't know why even if the id's are unique, without using p tags the .text() function is not adding the content to the p tags. Not sure why?

Comment: include the `form start & end` with your question.. please

Comment: @MarcB you're right, my bad.

Comment: @MarcB: If you notice i have added empty value attrib in the last hidden input. But that doesn't help either.

Comment: @sanki please include your `<form>` tag, because it's most likely to do with that...

Comment: @sanki: doesn't matter if it's empty. you're not **SETTING** that value attribute, so your form submits those names properly, but with empty strings as their values. you need something like `$('#id_rate').val('some value goes here');` to set the value, so something CAN be submitted.

Comment: @ChenAsraf : Just a min, i'll update my question

Comment: @MarcB: I have added some part jquery codes that sets the .val() function. I am geeing the right content and alerts as i mentioned before too. So i don't think setting the .val() function is an issue here.

Comment: @sam: The form is actually very very very long to be precise. So it might not help posting the whole form here.

Comment: @sanki, include the form tag please....

Comment: @Populus: I have included the link of the site, that may help you to see what the form looks like. Actually the form a really a long one so is suppose that's the right way to do it. Thanks

Comment: @sam: Posted the whole form from start to end. Please check

Comment: @sanki, I didn't tell you to post whole form codes.. I just told.. `start and end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your POST has duplicate entries.

Firebug:

```
first_EML   hgfhgfkjhkjh@kjhkh.com
first_n hgfhgf
first_n hgfhgf
na_10421    Tool for network identification iPhone
na_10422    Tool for network identification iPhone
na_2784 iPhone Rogers/fido
na_6117 iPhone Rogers/fido
na_7524 iPhone Rogers/fido
na_8303 iPhone Rogers/fido
na_9130 iPhone Telux/fido
na_9727 iPhone Telux/fido
na_apple    2784
na_bbm  2107
na_blackberry   Rogers/Fido Express
na_device   
na_device   
na_htc  653
na_lg   982
na_motorola 8475
na_nokia    10099
na_nokia    
na_rate 
na_rate 
na_rate 
na_samsung  7725
na_service  
na_service  
na_shtc Rogers/Fido Express
na_slg  LG International
na_smotorala    Rogers/Fido Express
na_sony_experia Rogers/Fido Express
na_sonye    658
na_sonyericsson SonyEricsson
na_sonyx    481
na_ssamsung Samsung Canada
```

Comment: Thanks for debugging. I found duplicate entry for name=na_rate everything else was fine. And after removing the redundancy i'm still not getting any value echoed $email.

Comment: You don't even have a POST variable called `email`. Did you get it from `first_EML`?

Comment: yes i am talking about firs_EML and i have stored the $_POST['first_EML'] in $email. I'm sorry that part isn't included in the code posted here.

Comment: The post value is there, so it's an issue with your PHP code, post that up please.

Comment: Check Updates, Posted whole form from start to end and relevant PHP codes too.